# How to embed own videos on Facebook with Flash Players? Is it still possible in 2017?

Tags: facebook, flash, video

I have been doing a lot of research for embedding my own videos on Facebook. I know that it is currently not possible to embed HTML5 player to Facebook, therefore I am trying to embed a flash video player, but even though I have followed almost all the answers given to similar questions on Stackoverflow, I haven't been succeed. That has risen the question in my mind if it is still possible to embed your own Flash player on Facebook today? I am also sharing my code below.

Thanks for answers in advance!

Here are my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Big Buck Bunny" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation." />
<meta property="og:video" content="https://gif-staging.herokuapp.com/static/player.swf?file=https://gif-staging.herokuapp.com/static/player.swf?file=https%3A%2F%2Fgif-staging.herokuapp.com%2Fstatic%2Fvideo.mp4&autostart=true&autostart=true" />
```

Comment: Provide a link to your testing html page with this code. A link that can be shared on FB wall to see any problem. Try to use a link without html entities (eg: no `%2F`, of course no spaces either).

Comment: Pretty sure your video URL is not supposed to contain `https://gif-staging.herokuapp.com/static/player.swf?file=` _twice_ ...